# How to set formatted text into a richtext field from an xpage button

Tags: xpages

I have a xpage that contains a button that pulls values from multiple fields, formats the text and sets that value into a rich text field on the backend document and saves it.

When I open the document on the Notes side the field is formatted correctly even though the field type indicates it is a Text.  When I open the document in the browser all formatting is lost and the text is one continuous string.  If I run an agent that contains @Command([ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs]) the field converts to Richtext and the xpage displays the contents correctly as well as the Notes Document.

Is there a way that I can set the value and retain the formatting or refresh the document to format the contents when saving the document from the web?

Sample code from button

```
var val;
var surveystandard = getComponent("FStandard").value;
var totalspaces = getComponent("TotalSpaces").value;
....

//Parking
if (!!totalspaces){
    val = val + "\n";
    val = val + "PARKING" + "\n";
    val = val + "\u25cf" + "\t" + "There are " + totalspaces + " parking spaces, with " + accessiblespaces + " marked accessible spaces, " + vanspaces + " of these are marked van accessible, " + carspacesrequired + " car accessible space(s) and " + vanspacesrequired + " van accessible space are required.";
    val = val + "\n";
if (parking != "" && totalspaces == ""){
    val = val + "PARKING" + "\n";
    formattedValue = formatCustomList(parking, customparking);
    val = val + formattedValue;  ........

//Set value **********

document1.setValue("Notes", val);
```

I've tried a couple of things using a NotesRichTextItem but they didn't work..

```
var notesRTF:NotesRichTextItem = document1.getDocument().createRichTextItem("Notes");
notesRTF.appendText(val);
```

This code generates an error....

Script interpreter error, line=749, col=58: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.createRichTextItem(string) null

Once the script block finishes there is a Save Document step that executes a simple action.

Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See me blog entry on this: http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/12/xpages-dynamically-updating-rich-text-content-in-a-ckeditor.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.createRichTextItem(string) null
```

This error message occured when the document already contained the rich text item with the same name.
Check first if the item exists already or not.

---

Update:
It seems the same javascript variable can not be used to store different rtitems:

```
var rtMegjegyzesek:NotesRichTextItem=ugyDoc.createRichTextItem('megjegyzesek');                     
var rtMegjegyzesek:NotesRichTextItem=ugyDoc.createRichTextItem('megjegyzesekExport');
```

This lines above raised the same error...